# What Does initWithNibName really do anyway?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

```
theTestController = [[[CustomCell alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]autorelease];
```

My guess is that it will load CustomCell and set theTestController as the owner. If so:

1. Why in most sample code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I see `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner: theTestController options:nil]`; instead?
2. What is the difference between `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner: theTestController options:nil];` and `theTestController = [[[CustomCell alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]autorelease];`
3. I tried replacing `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner: theTestController options:nil];`   with  `theTestController = [[[CustomCell alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]autorelease];` and I got errors. Looks like the outlets remain `nil` if I use the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`initWithNibName:bundle:` is convenience method declared in `UIViewController` and is available to its subclasses. This will initialize the view controller by loading the nib, probably by using `loadNibName:owner:options:` method internally.

`initWithNibName:bundle:` is unavailable to `UIView` and its subclasses. So we have to make use of `loadNibName:owner:options:` to load views.

1. Custom cells are `UIView` subclasses and hence make use of `loadNibName:owner:options:`.
2. Not much difference. `initWithNibName:bundle:` is a convenience method for `UIViewController` initialization.
3. You are getting errors because of the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: CustomCell is a Controller, not a view. Sorry for not making that clear. The code compile. I wouldn't if CustomCell is just a UIView